# Wearing Tallis Like a Scarf

Tags: tallit-gadol

The [Kaf Hachaim (8:9)](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.8.9.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes

> אותם בני אדם שמניחין הטלית כשהוא מקופל ומשלשלים סביב צוארם על כתפיהם
>   בענין שקצה האחד כשהוא מקופל עם ב' ציציות יורד לפניו בצד ימין וקצה השני
>   עם שני ציציות יורד לפניו משמאל אין יוצאין בכה"ג ידי מצות ציצית וגוערים
>   בהם דכה"ג לכ"ע לא עיטוף הוא - those people who put their tallis folded around their necks over their shoulders so that both the front/back tzitzis sit in front of them do not fulfill their mitzva of tzitzis and you should tell them that according to everyone this is not considered wrapping oneself in a tallis.

Are there any sources who consider wearing the tallis in such a scarf-like fashion to fulfill the mitzva? (If there are none, what's the best way to help a stranger understand this in shul without offending him?)

Comment: I've seen Yemenite Jews wear their tallis this way. They're big though, unlike the Reform scarfs.

Comment: @JoshK, that's about small garments; this is about full-size ones worn folded.

Comment: @JoshK Thank you for linking the other question - I was looking more for a Torah source which allows wearing the tallis in this fashion rather than a cultural or historical source.